# Random walk with bounds and pauses in 1-d

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

**EDIT**: There was a point that I had misunderstood and hence modifying the question slightly. The boundary at $N$ is *sticky*, not bouncing. The boundary at $1$ is a *bouncing* boundary.

How do we calculate the *number of walks* that would reach a value $N$ given that:

1. There are three operations with identical probability of occurrence: $\{+1, 0, -1\}$ , i.e., a right $(r)$, pause$(p)$ and a left $(\ell)$ if we consider the 1-d as the positive x-axis.
2. The total number of operations in the walk is fixed as $K$.
3. The walk starts at $1$ and cannot go less than $1$ or greater than $N$, i.e., it is bounded on both ends. A walk that reaches $N$ with more operations remaining can do $p$ operations only, i.e, it is a *sticky* boundary. However $1$ is a *bouncing* boundary.

Basic combinatorics says that the number of walks ignoring bounds will be 
$$\sum_p  \frac{(\ell + r + p)!}{\ell! r! p!}$$ where $p$ ranges from $0$ to $K-N$, $\ell+r+p = K$ and $r-\ell = N$, but this will have many walks that go beyond the boundaries. I am unable to proceed further.

In other words, this is the number of *ordered* sets of cardinality $K$ from the alphabet $\{1, 0, -1\}$ which have a *total sum* of $N$ and any sum of a *"prefix-subset"* of elements is *positive*.

I am trying to find a **closed form solution for the number of walks** but unable to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Fischler for the edits!

Comment: Please use the edit button to look at the form which is "tex-ified"

Comment: Also, you could be a bit more precise about your conditions at $1$ and $N$.  From your statement, I take it to mean that $N$ is "sticky" (that is, being at $N$ forces the next step to be $p$), and that the $1$ boundary is a bouncing boundary (that is, being at $1$ forces the next step to be $r$ or $p$ but not $\ell$).

Comment: @MarkFischler thanks for the comment. I clarified it. It is actually not sticky but is bouncing on both ends.

Comment: Simply subtract all the walks that arrive to the same point but reach one step past the boundary on the way there and apply reflection principle to compute that. This will only address the number of walks and ignore that probabilities on the boundary change.

Comment: @A.S. if the number of walks I want is $W(N, K)$, the walks you mention is $W(N+1, K-1-p)$ on the RHS boundary, where $p$ can be some number of pauses. So we would sum over $p$ and subtract it is it ?

Comment: @A.S. thanks and I got the answer for this question using the way you mentioned, but I mistakenly said that the RHS (at $N$) was bouncing while it was actually sticky. Could you tell me how to handle this ? I can raise a new question if needed. The issue with sticky is that the the last set of (1 right, many pauses) would be repeated and I'm not able to count it.